# Can we add android geofence to the polygons in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-geofence

I am developing an app to monitor the Geofence in google maps android,but in geofence Builder class only we can set circular region,is their any class that we can use polygons to monitor the geofences,please help me
Thanks And Regards

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't do it directly but you can try a workaround like https://stackoverflow.com/a/32133568/2401535.

Comment: But I used some algorithm to determine whether the location is inside or outside the polygon.considering polygonal has a Geofence

Comment: Another problem is when i create a **circular Geofence**using google maps api.Since Geofence takes default location but ,how to track other user location taken from the back end rather then our current location and determine the user is inside or utside the Geofence.