# Making non-circlular geofence in Android

Tags: android, android-geofence

I just started to play with new Google Location API, particularly with GeoFence. I have an assignment to provide geofence based on four coordinates. So, I'm wondering about how to do it. Most of examples show only radial solution(so, and `Geofence.Builder()` has `setCircularRegion()` only). What is the possible way to implement non-circular geofence?

Comment: Probably answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847977/android-build-polygonal-shape-geofence)?

Comment: That is currently not possible with the Geofencing API. You can only make circular geofences.